# Ito's Process Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am self studying stochastic calc and in my book it says:

Given that
$$ Y(t)=Y(0) + \int_{o}^{t} \mu (s) ds \ +\int_{o}^{t} \sigma (s) dB(s) $$
and therefore;
$$dY(t)= \mu (t)dt+\sigma(t)dB(t)$$
We can show that
$$B^{2}(t)=t+2 \int_{o}^{t} B(s)dB(s)$$

By setting $Y(t) = B^{2}(t)$ and therefore $\mu (s) = 1$ and $\sigma (s) = 2B(s)$

I was wondering how the mu and sigma values were derived. The book skips over this bit and gives it as a statement, then jumps straight to $d(B^{2}(t))=2B(t)dB(t)+dt$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can derive the display formula using the Itō-formula. Then $\mu(s)=1$ and $\sigma(s)=2B(s)$ follows from that, because the representation of an Ito-process is a.s. unique.

Comment: Does the book literally says that? I guess there are some assumptions on μ and σ –

Comment: @AdriánHinojosaCalleja Its from Intro to Stoch Calc. with Applications by F. Klebaner (pg 126 for what its worth). Its generally a good book - covers a lot of topics but very much in a "just in passing" sort of way

Answer (score 1):

I have the book you mentioned, so I went to check out what exactly is written there. It is page 108 in the 3rd edition of Klebaner. I think you are overthinking this. The point the author is trying to make is that $B^2(t)$ is an Ito process as it can be written in the required form.

---

So here is how you should read this page. First, we have the definition of Ito process as a process that can be expressed as
\begin{align}
Y(t) = Y(0) + \int_0^t \mu(s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s)dB(s), \quad 0\leq t \leq T, \quad(\ast)
\end{align}
where $\mu(s)$ and $\sigma(s)$ satisfy suitable integrability conditions. Then, we are told that the above process can be written in a differential form as
\begin{align}
dY(t)=\mu(t)dt+\sigma(t)dB(t)
\end{align}
The two forms really say the same things, though only the first equation has a proper meaning as Klebaner remarks.

---

Then, as an example Klebaner shows that $B^2(t)$ is an Ito process. This requires us to write $B^2(t)$ in the form of Equation $(\ast)$.

To do so, note that in an example in the previous section, which is a simple application of Ito Lemma, it was shown that
\begin{align}
B^2(t)=2 \int_0^t B(s)dB(s) + t
\end{align}
To see that this defines an Ito process, we note that the above equation can be written as
\begin{align}
B^2(t)=B(0) + \int_0^t 1 ds+  \int_0^t 2B(s)dB(s) 
\end{align}
Therefore, by setting $\mu(s)=1$ and $\sigma(s)=2B(s)$ we see that this last equation maps exactly into the definition of an Ito process.